# Problem with Django on Centos 6

Tags: centos, python, icinga2

I have a problem to install graphite on server Centos 6.8 :

```
Error: Package: graphite-web-0.9.16-2.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: Django >= 1.3
Error: Package: python-django-tagging-0.3.1-7.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: Django
```

but, I installed Django from pip on python2.6:

```
 # python -c 'import django; print(django.get_version())'
1.6
```

yum can't find some additional Django package , so , may be somebody can help me install graphite on Centos 6

- I can't update Centos to version 7.
- is problematic to update python .

Comment: The package you are attempting to install, `graphite-web` from EPEL, has a dependency on the EPEL packaged Django, which you stated is not installed since you installed from `pip`.  EPEL offers Django 1.11, but if you do not intend to use the EPEL packaged version, you could try to install `graphite-web` [from the source](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web).  You would need to use a version before 1.0 if you want to continue using Django 1.6 (versions after 1.0 require Django 1.8).

Comment: CentOS 6 is dead. Anything that used to work with CentOS 6 and EPEL is not going to work anymore, since EPEL6 is gone.  You’d be better off spending your time getting the software working on a supported platform than trying to perform necromancy on old, dead platforms.